# Mobile app for remote control from a computer to take photos and save them on the computer

Tags: photography, remote-access, desktop-client, animation, mobile

I want to use a mobile phone to capture images and transfer them to my computer to create a stop motion animation.

On the mobile phone I have access to iphone, android or windows phone.

The computer is windows 8.1 or mac with os x yosemite.

I do not want to jailbreak any of the phones.

I don't want to have to press buttons on the phone to take a picture, I want to control that without touching the phone by pressing a button on my computer.

I want to get the images onto the computer as they are taken.

Comment: Just a quick idea: Use DLNA: Set up your phone as a video stream provider, then use a renderer on the Desktop side, that allows for "screen capture".

Answer (score 1):

If you search for time lapse you get suggestions as the Instagram's [Hyperlapse](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id740146917) (for iOS), or [LapseIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ui.LapseItPro&hl=en), [Hyper Timelapse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobyi.hypertimelapse), [Framelapse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Nishant.Singh.DroidTimelapse&hl=en) which are three alternatives for Android. These however seem to make the timelapse on the smartphone, and not on your computer.

To take remote photos and automagically get the images onto your computer I see a two-folded solution:

- Trigger the smartphone camera from your computer. Look into programs like [Camera remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.busywww.cameraremote) or [AirDroid (see Remote camera section)](http://www.androidauthority.com/airdroid-control-android-from-pc-269186/), or look into [How to turn android/iphone into spy camera or baby monitor](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-turn-android-iphone-into-spy-camera-or-baby-monitor/)
- Automagically sync the photos to your computer, this can be done using autosync to Dropbox, Google+, and more. See [Five apps to move photos from your smartphone to your pc](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2150826/five-apps-to-move-photos-from-your-smartphone-to-your-pc.html), or [How can I back up and sync my androids pictures without plugging it in](http://lifehacker.com/5733845/how-can-i-back-up-and-sync-my-androids-pictures-without-plugging-it-in) or a program like [PhotoSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchbyte.photosync)

Either way you seem to have some reading and configuring to get the setup you want. For me I think I would go for using default sync to either Dropbox or Google+, and then use either something like the mentioned AirDroid, or possibly some macro program to take pictures at given intervals.